# Change cell color based on other cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have encountered numerous questions related to changing a cell color based on its value, which can be achieve easily with Excel "Conditional Formatting". However I'm interested in changing a cell color based on some other cell value.

For example, I want cell `A4` to be painted red only if cell `B4` has a greater value than `A4` cell. Is there any way to accomplish that?

I've found [this](http://www.exceldigest.com/myblog/2009/04/16/conditional-formatting-in-excel-2007-based-on-value-of-another-cell/) guide which actually explains what I need pretty well, but how can I expand this formatting to numerous cells? Just dragging doesn't work here for me.

**EDIT**:
I'm using the Excel 2007 version.

Answer (score 13):

[Conditional formatting in Excel 2007 (based on value of another cell)](http://www.exceldigest.com/myblog/2009/04/16/conditional-formatting-in-excel-2007-based-on-value-of-another-cell/)

1. Select the cell you want to format, “A1″ in this example.
2. In the Home tab, Styles group, click on Conditional Formatting.
3. Select New Rule.

   [image]
4. The New Formatting Rule window will open.

   [image]
5. Click Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
6. The New Formatting Rule window will now look like this:

   [image]
7. In the edit box labeled “Format values where this formula is true“, enter “=” followed  by a formula referencing the other cell. In this example the formula: “=B1<0″ is entered.
8. Click the Format button. The Format Cells window will open.

   [image]
9. Specify the formatting you want. In this example I changed the cell color to “RED”.
10. Click OK to close The Format Cells window.
11. Click OK to close The New Formatting Rule window.

To summarize this example: cell A1 will have a RED color when cell B1 value is less than zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it seems that these directives are for older version of Excel. I use 2007 version and I can't perform these steps directly. I will update my question with Excel version.

Comment: @EugeneS changed to Excel 2007

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Can you just please add an instruction as to how can I expand this conditional formatting to multiple cells? For example I want cells `A1` to `A5` be dependent on cells `B1` to `B5` respectively.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you intend to do on this dependency, but if it is the same, just select a range on step 1. Or even copy and paste the entire cell to the folowing one.

Comment: Choosing a range of cells won't help here since this formatting applies for each individual cell only. You can see that in Step 6 I have to show explicitly which specific cell I want to format. What I want is just that cell `A1` format will be dependent on cell `B1`, cell `A2` format will be dependent on cell `B2` and so on...

Comment: Just use the + drag icon and drop until the row that you want after applying the rule... I just this it here and it worked for me..

Comment: @Eugene Diogo's instructions are already very straightforward. You can drag the cells or use Paste Special > Format OR go to Manage Rules and just adjust the range in the Applies To field to cover cells A2 to A5.

Comment: The dragging option to expand wouldn't be feasible for the example given in the question. As A1 contains a value to be compared to B1, dragging A1 will also change the value of cells A2:A5 not just the formattting. You `can` choose a range, Eugene, (at step 1 in Diogo's instructions) - when you do that in conditional formatting the formula you use applies to the `first cell` (top left) in the range and the formula implicitly adjusts for each cell in the range in the same way that a formula would change if it were in a worksheet cell and you dragged it......