# I want to highlght the largest value of one column based on a > criteria of another

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I want to highlight the largest percentage in one column, but it has to be based on the quantity in an adjacent cell being greater than say 20. Can I do this with conditional formatting?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Hi Randy. Welcome to SuperUser. Your question seems a bit vague. For example, wouldn't the highest percentage in a column always be the highest, regardless of if it's greater than say 20 or 50 or 16? You may want to review the [How do I ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and conduct a bit of research on SuperUser too. It sounds like [this previous answer](https://superuser.com/questions/442698/change-cell-color-based-on-other-cell-value?rq=1) may be what you're looking for. If you can't find a good starting point, please edit your question to provide more detail.

Comment: @jrichall - It's what I would expect to see if there were standard line items and customised stock. The custom jobs should have a significantly higher percentage profit. If I wanted the highest profit for standard items, with no special code to say its custom or standard, excluding items with a trivial amount of sales and then searching would be one method.

Comment: @Alan you got all of that from OP's question? I'm impressed! I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2016

You can do it with one of the statistical functions introduced in 2016.

```
=MAXIFS(max_range,criteria_range,criteria)
```

E.g. `=MAXIFS($A$1:$A$10,$B$1:$B$10,">20")`

Wrap this up in an `IF` statement.

```
=IF(A1:A11=MAXIFS($A$1:$A$10,$B$1:$B$10,">20"), TRUE, FALSE)
```

[image]

Prior to 2016, you'd probably need an array formula.

```
=MAX(IF($B$1:$B$11>20,$A$1:$B$11))
```

If you put that in a worksheet cell, you'll need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter rather than enter (it'll show up inside curly braces {}).

In conditional formatting, array formulae are automatically processed with no special actions required.

See [here](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/11/19/using-max-if-with-multiple-criteria/) and [here](http://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/june-2016-excel-array-formulas-in-conditional-formatting/).